# Building a CalDAV-server in PHP?

Tags: php, caldav

Ok, so I'm the author of a CMS and I'm interested in building a CalDAV-server that enables the user to interface with my CMS through CalDAV instead of only through the web, so they can see their calendars, add todos and things like that.

I've looked at http://www.davical.org/ which is a CalDAV service built in PHP, but it has its own database and I already have the DB stuff done and just want a middle-layer services that translates, both ways, to and from my databases using my functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

SabreDAV http://sabre.io/dav/caldav/ can be of some help.

Comment: SabreDAV seems to be a HUGE project, and the example files are just a mess for someone wanting a simple way to expose data via these protocols... Hmmm, but it seems to be the only viable choice

Comment: I feel offended! ;) Seriously though, CalDAV is a _hard_ to implement protocol. And doing it in such a way that it's not just a packaged server, but something others can build on top off makes it hard. I opted for a 'heavy bootstrap' so it's very easy for people to swap out some objects, but I'm open to ideas as well.

Comment: @Evert Sorry, didn't mean to offend. I have to sit down and take the time to figure this one out, how to best apply SabreDAV to my CMS environment.

Comment: It was mostly a joke =)

Answer (score 7):

You should definitely have a look at Baïkal. It's a lightweight caldav and carddav server distribution based on SabreDAV and SQLite3.

http://baikal-server.com/

Answer (score 0):

DAViCal also has hooks that you can use to synchronise with your own table structure, in particular it has this hook which is called whenever a change occurs within a calendar:

http://wiki.davical.org/w/Configuration/hooks/log_caldav_action